# How to adjust the size and numbering the elements/items in table?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm new in LaTeX and made a table using the following script:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c}
    \hline
    Semantic Database & Relational Database \\
    \hline
    Meanings of  information are stored & Meanings of information are lost\\
    Relationships between the classes& Relationships are not supported\\
    No restriction on data type/size& Restricted type/size \\
    No primary/secondary keys are required& Keys are required and are static \\
    A variety of queries can be run (any relation can be viewed)& Most of the queries must be anticipated (heavy joins are required)\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A COMPARISON BETWEEN SEMANTIC DATABASE AND RELATIONAL DATABASE}\label{tab:dh}
\end{table}
```

But the problem is that I am unable to adjust the table in PDF file. As shown [image: here].

And also add numbers with the items.

Comment: Your post is very unclear. Please clarify what you want to adjust in the table and were you want to add "numbers with the items", so we can try to help you.

Comment: Please see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables for various examples, most likely you will get what you want. If not, please clarify your question as stated by @An economist.